Как задать конкретную сетевую карту для выхода в интернет?
Есть несколько сетевых карт, установленных в ПК (Шиндовс 10), каждая подключена к своему уникальному маршрутизатору со своим внешним ip. Как задать только одну конкретную сетевую карту для выхода в интернет с данного ПК?

начните со статьи в википедии.

Убрать Default gateway со всех остальных карт.

Задать default маршрут для всех карт и для нужной карты установить самую низкую метрику. Это позволит автоматически переключить интернет, если на основной будет link-down.

Попробовал обойтись советом @balbes, установил метрику равную 1, и на всякий случай убрал DNS с остальных карт. На данный момент работает как надо.

В качестве DNS в такой схеме, лучше использовать внешний 1.1.1.1,  8.8.8.8 или др. Если требуется копоративный, прописать к нему долнительный маршрут, через нужную карту, тогда Интернет будет через одну карту, а DNS сможет работать через другую.
